# Identify the customers, who ordered the same article more than once and list it

Tags: mysql

I have a table A that contains a few columns with entries. In column 1 is customer number which can occur more than once (in the table). In column 2 is the article-number which can also occur more than once in the table.

Now what I want to do: I want identify the customers, who ordered the same article more than once. To do that I want a query that will show the ordered articles (by article number) every customer ordered and the quantity he or she ordered (in another column)

Here´s an example:

For example if the table A contained:

```
|col1                           ||col2           |
+--------------------------------+---------------+
|1                              ||1              |
|2                              ||2              |
|3                              ||5              |
|1                              ||2              |
|2                              ||2              |
|2                              ||4              |    
|1                              ||1              | 
|3                              ||8              |
```

I want a query that will select:

```
|col1                           ||col2           ||col3|
+--------------------------------+---------------+-----+
|1                              ||1              |  2  |
|1                              ||2              |  1  |
|2                              ||2              |  2  |
|2                              ||4              |  1  |
|3                              ||5              |  1  |                              
|3                              ||8              |  1  |
```

This what I got so far:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(col2) AS ABC FROM A GROUP BY col1
```

-> But this is not working correctly...

Comment: What does not working correctly mean?

Comment: I think if you add group `by col2` at the end it should work as you want.

Comment: So the solution is : SELECT *, COUNT(col2) AS ABC FROM A GROUP BY col1, col2 ?!

Comment: Yes, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes: it worked! Thanks a lot